# How to use livedata in an MVVM architecture

Tags: android, callback, firebase-authentication, android-livedata, android-architecture

TLDR: How could I properly implement an MVVM architecture with LiveData?

I have a fragment class that observe a viewModel exposed livedata:

#### viewModel.loginResultLiveData.observe

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginBinding

    private val viewModel by fragmentScopedViewModel { injector.loginViewModel }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val username = binding.loginInputField.toString()
        val password = binding.passwordInputField.toString()

        binding.loginSignInButton.setOnClickListener {  viewModel.login(
            username,
            password
        ) }

        viewModel.loginResultLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            when(it){
                is LoginResult.Success -> doSmth()
            }
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

View model class simply ask for a mapped livedata object.

```
class LoginViewModel @Inject internal constructor(
    private val loginUseCase: LoginUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    lateinit var loginResultLiveData: MutableLiveData<LoginResult>

    fun login(username: String, password: String) {
        loginResultLiveData = loginUseCase.login(username, password)
    }
}
```

Model uses use case, to map a result from the original format and also would map errors:

```
class LoginUseCase @Inject internal constructor(
    private val authRepository: AuthEmailRepository
) {
    var loginResultLiveData = MutableLiveData<LoginResult>()

    fun login(userName: String, password: String): MutableLiveData<LoginResult> {
        authRepository.login(userName, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    loginResultLiveData.postValue(LoginResult.Success)
                } else {
                    loginResultLiveData.postValue(LoginResult.Fail(it.exception.toString()))
                }
            }
        return loginResultLiveData
    }
}
```

The problem is that only after `loginSignInButton`is clicked, the model creates a liveData object. But I'm starting to observe this object immediately after onClickListener is set. Also each time a button is clicked, this would create a new instance of `viewModel.loginResultLiveData`, which doesn’t make sense.

```
  binding.loginSignInButton.setOnClickListener {  viewModel.login(
        username,
        password
    ) }

    viewModel.loginResultLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
        when(it){
            is LoginResult.Success -> doSmth()
        }
    }
```

How could I properly implement MVVM architecture with LiveData in this case?

I could also move logic I now have in `LoginUseCase`to ModelView and then have something like this, which avoids the problem described before. But then I cannot delegate mapping/error handling to use case.

```
class LoginViewModel @Inject internal constructor(
    private val loginUseCase: LoginUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    val loginResult: MutableLiveData<LoginResult> = MutableLiveData()

    fun login(username: String, password: String) = loginUseCase.login(username, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                loginResult.postValue(LoginResult.Success)
            } else {
                loginResult.postValue(LoginResult.Fail(it.exception.toString()))
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to observe a mutable LiveData that is only initialized after the `onClickListener` so you won't get it to work, also you have a `lateinit` property that is only initialized if you call the login method which will throw an exception.

To solve your problem you can have a `MediatorLiveData` that will observe your other live data and pass the result back to your fragment observer.

You can try the following:

```
class LoginViewModel @Inject internal constructor(
    private val loginUseCase: LoginUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    private var _loginResultLiveData = MediatorLiveData<LoginResult>()
    val loginResultLiveData: LiveData<LoginResult> = _loginResultLiveData

    fun login(username: String, password: String) {
        val loginUseCaseLiveData = loginUseCase.login(username, password)
        _loginResultLiveData.addSource(loginUseCaseLiveData) {
            _loginResultLiveData.value = it
        }
    }
}
```